# Update then delete child table's value on deleting parent record Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I have two tables Order and OrderItem where OrderItem has the order_id as foreign key from Orders table. I have used laravel relationship in each of their model. Upon deleting a record from Order table which has relation in the OrderItem, I want to update a column name "Cancel" to true in OrderItem table and then soft delete the record.
I only know the manual method where I find the record by id, then update and soft delete it. Can anyone help me with shorter and easier method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mean is `soft delete`.

you can see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scout#soft-deleting) document.

Comment: I have done soft delete, the only thing I want is to update the child record firrst when deleting the praent only then delete(soft-delete) child record

Comment: see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers